# PHP - Can I shift an array from a specific key?

Tags: php, arrays

I was having a little trouble with my array in PHP.

I have the following the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [2] => raspberry
    [3] => kiwi
    [4] => cherry
    [5] => nuts
)
```

But I want to kick out 'kiwi' and shift all other keys up, to get the following...

```
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [2] => raspberry
    [3] => cherry
    [4] => nuts
)
```

I am sure someone here knows how to get it done, php's shift only takes to first key and not something specific.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array-splice/) does for you. It even lets you insert new entries there if you so choose.

For this specific case you use:

```
array_splice($array, 3, 1);
```

Comment: Does it regenerate the keys?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, No kidding.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It works out fine by e.g.: array_splice($array , 3, 1);

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, There is not any inbuilt function to do this, but you can create one. What you have to do is, delete an specific element and then recalculate the keys.

```
function a_shift($index, $array) {
     unset($array[$index));
     return array_values($array);
}
```

Comment: Um... What's the purpose of `array_map` here?

Comment: @Kolink, It will create a new array from the values only, thus resetting the keys. And because this is part of my bigger function I forgot to remove the case for nested arrays.

Comment: Um, no it won't. It will iterate through each element of the array, and return the values of *that* array, throwing an error if any of the parent array's elements are not arrays... Just `return array_values($arra);` will do.

Comment: @Kolink, I was still completing my comment. Please read again.

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array("banana", "apple", "raspberry", "kiwi", "cherry", "nuts");
$key = array_search('kiwi', $array);
unset($array[$key]);
$array = array_values($array);
print_r($array);

Output:
Array ( [0] => banana [1] => apple [2] => raspberry [3] => cherry [4] => nuts )
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to remove keys from one array and copy to another:

```
$keys = [1, 3];
foreach ($keys as $index => $key) {
    if ($index != 0) {
        $key -= $index;
    }
    $newArr[] = array_splice($oldArr, $key, 1)[0];
}
return $newArr;
```